# Have I correctly or incorrectly found the Y confidence probability using z-scores?

Tags: statistics

Using the information from the histogram and assuming that this measure of confidence in institutions is normally distributed. Determine the probability that a randomly drawn respondent has Y confidence in institutions where Y:

Histogram: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKrEJ.jpg

⦁   is greater than or equal to 8

⦁   is less than or equal to 5

⦁   lies between 7 and 9

⦁   Estimate the score equal to p90

I thought to use z-scores here so then:

Mean = 6

sd = 2

for the first part:

z-score = (8-6)/2 = 1

p(z>1) 1 - p(z<1) = 1 - .8413 = .1587 or 15.87percent

for the second part:

z-score = (5-6)/2 = -1/2 = -0.5

p(z<-0.5) = .3085 or 30.85percent

for the third part:

z-score = 7-6/2 = 0.5 = .6915 
z-score = 9-6/2 = 1.5 = .9332 
p(7 < z < 9) = .9332 - .6915 = .2417 or 24.17percent

Can someone please tell me if what I've done is incorrect or correct.

Also confused on how to estimate the score equal to P90 percentile.

Please help 
Thank you

Comment: I haven't checked the numbers but you seem to have the right idea in the calculations you did. The 90th percentile should be a score $Y_1$ such that $P(Y<Y_1) = 0.9.$ If you're using a table of the normal cumulative distribution you can search it for probabilities close to $0.9.$

Comment: I checked and it's .8159

So I am trying to isolate Y_i. Not sure I totally know how to do this.

Comment: Would it be 81.59%?

Comment: That looks like you set $Z=0.9$ and looked it up. What you want for a percentile is the other way around: what value of $Z$ do you need so that when you look up the probability, you get $0.9$?

Comment: It occurs to me that writing $0.5=.6915$ is not only technically wrong, it makes it harder to describe what you're doing. Instead of writing $Z=(7-6)/2 = 0.5=.6915,$ you might write $Z=(7-6)/2=0.5,$ $P(Y<7) = P(Z<0.5) = .6915.$ (But note the "continuity correction" in the answer below, which I forgot in my earlier comments.)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I understand the question wrong for the P90. It's asking for what score would one have to get to be within the 90th percentile, is that right? So what I am looking for is the score or Y_i

Comment: @DavidK as an added check is there any way you could please check to see if what I have for my solutions is correct? Thank you

Comment: It seems that you have two accounts: [yre](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/428730/yre) and [Foo Fighter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/288768/foo-fighter)

Comment: You can compare the calculated values with this [table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662358/percentiles-and-quartiles-have-i-mis-understood-this-statistics-question-quest) (link). It seems that the graph is created based on this table.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- **ad a)** First of all this is a discrete distribution. That means $P(X\geq 8)=1-P(X\leq 7)$. And therefore you need additionally the
  continuity correction factor $0.5$.

  $$P(X\geq 8)\approx 1-\Phi\left( \frac{7+0.5-6}{2} \right)=1-\Phi\left(
     0.75\right) $$

  Using this [online calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx) we get $P(X\geq 8)\approx 1-0.773=0.227=22.7\%$. Note that this is an approximation.
- Similar for **b)**-add the continuity correction factor.
- **ad c)** If we interpete this as $P(7\leq  X\leq 9)$ then you have to calculate

  $P(7\leq  X\leq 9)=P(X\leq 9)-P(X\leq 6)$

Comment: Sorry, this just sort of confused me.Were my solutions incorrect?

Comment: @FooFighter Yes. You have to regard that X is a discrete random variable. Could you comprehend the solution for a)?

Comment: To check my result at a) you can read of the values for $X=8,9,10 $ from the graph and add them. From what I could read off from the graph the values are  $P(X\geq 8)=12\%+7\%+3\%=22\%$

Comment: Why x<=7? the way I've seen these problems set-up is where you have a p(z>n) = 1 - p(z<n). The form you are using is unlike what I've been taught.

Comment: Will it be. 22% for the first, 37% for the second, and 36% for the third. With a P_90 being around 9.0?

Comment: @yre First question: If a random variable is `discrete` (here grouped) then $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x-1)$. For `continuous` random variables it is $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x)$ In case of continuous r.v. it is $P(X\leq x)=P(X<x)$. But this is not true for discrete r.v. And you have to pay attention on wether you have $\leq$ or $<$ a relation sign.

Comment: @yre And please don´t wait 2 hours or more to give an reply. It would take to long to come to an end with your question(s)-maybe days.

Comment: @callculus sorry. Are my solutions correct?

Comment: @yre What have you calculated? Please show your calculations. You can make an edit of your question. And why 22%? I got 22.7%

Comment: @callculus sorry, but quick side question. If my mean=500 and my SD = 100, and I want to find the scores between 400 and 700, would the solution be 0.1357. Because when I calculated 400 I got z=0.8413 and for 700 I got z=0.9772 so subtracting smaller from bigger: 0.9772 - 0.8413 = 0.1357

Comment: @yre For $P(X<400)=\Phi\left(\frac{400-500}{100} \right)=\Phi\left(-1 \right)=0.159$ The result is not for z since $z=-1$. It is $P(X<400)=\Phi\left(-1 \right)=0.159$

Comment: @callculus Thank you. I think I am going to have to spend a lot of time figuring this out. So the solution would be 0.9772 - 0.159?

Comment: @callculus What I don't understand is the phi out front, what exactly does that mean?

Comment: @yre Yes, the result is correct. $\Phi(z)$ is the cummulative distribution function of the standard normal distributed random variable. The random variable $Z$ is distributed as $Z\sim \mathcal  N(0,1)$ The relation is $P\left(Z<z \right)=P\left(Z<-1 \right)=\Phi(-1)$.